# How can I set Déjà Dup to keep backups for less than six months?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

Déjà Dup allows me to choose whether to keep backups for six months, a year, or forever.

[image: Screenshot showing three options]

How do I choose to keep backups for less than six months, say, three months, or even more?

Comment: Hmm intriging: here https://live.gnome.org/DejaDup/HowItWorks they speak of "keep backups" "monthly" ... Settings seem to be stored in `'~/.gconf/apps/deja-dup/%conf.xml` but it is not very nice to go through ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to modify the Dconf setting at path `/org/gnome/deja-dup/`, schema `org.gnome.DejaDup`, key name `delete-after`. It's set to the number of days to keep backup files on backup location.

For example, to set it to 60 days from the command line, run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.DejaDup delete-after 60
```

You can also do this from `dconf-editor`:

[image: Screenshot]

The Backup Déjà Dup utility reacts well to this change, adding it as an option:

[image: Screenshot of "Keep backups" option, showing new option "At least 60 days"]

Comment: Note that Deja Dup internally tries to keep at least two full backups on the backup location.  So if you want to set a lower custom delete-after value, you should also lower the full-backup-period key to about half that.