# 14.04 automatic ssh sync tool needed(backup)

Tags: ssh, backup, encryption, sync, cloud

Currently I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I would wish to make an automatic backup of my local drive to the university server. This server I can access to via ssh (no root rights). I am looking for a solution which automatically(in a time period f.e. a day) synchronizes chosen local folders with the ones at the server.(Just one way, so I change things at my local notebook and the change is uploaded to the server) A client-side encryption would be nice to have but is not necessary.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** What you want is backup and not sync. Sync is not backup. For example, if you sync a local folder to a remote folder and delete a file in the local folder, it will get deleted from the remote when the folders sync. Then you won't have that file in either of the folders and there will be no way to get it back.

The default backup software, Déjà Dup included with Ubuntu should be able to backup to the remote ssh server. It allows encryption as well.  [Search here](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=deja+dup+ssh) for related questions.

If you want a sync, look into [lsyncd](https://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/). It is in the Ubuntu repository. That means you can install it using the *Ubuntu Software Center* or the command `sudo apt-get install lsyncd`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything I looked for was already there! Hopefully this here helps to automatically remove the old backups: http://askubuntu.com/questions/245708/how-can-i-set-d%C3%A9j%C3%A0-dup-to-keep-backups-for-less-than-six-months/246708#246708